# Ext net resource manager on master page and explicit mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, ext.net

I have my resource manager on my master page, and some controls are render by it. 
On one of my pages I needed Ext.Net.IDMode.Explicit for some reasons.

Problem is that the master's controls have ClientID and when direct events are called the resource manager is unable to get those controls on this function :

```
if(groupCallback)
{
  groupCallback=
  {
    fn:groupCallback,
    counter:config.length||1,
    config:config,
    step:function()
    {
      this.counter--;
      if(this.counter===0)
      {
        this.fn.apply(window,[this.config]);
      }
    }
  };
}
```

So, how can I rename all the controls as Explicit on this page or prevent the call of this function ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

My field was called on page_load, a `if (!this.IsPostBack)` solved the problem.